# If Mary could be conceived without the stain of original sin, why didn't God do this for all people?

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary, original-sin, immaculate-conception

If the Blessed Virgin was immaculately conceived without the stain of original sin and be full of grace so that she would not even want to sin, why didn't God do this for all people?

Comment: Welcome to the site Suryetto. Unfortunately your question has already been asked here. If you can edit it, in order to make it a different question, please do so. You can then flag your question for reopening. Hope you stay with us.